# Force "Stage" & "Probability" to Stay in Sync

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I am fairly new to formulas and would like to write a validation rule that enforces the relationship between opportunity stage and probability (so that the two will always be in sync), but I only want this rule applied to two specific Opportunity Record Types, let's call them Record Types "A" and "B."

This link https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giLOAAY was somewhat helpful, but I don't know to add in the condition that the rules ONLY applies to Record Types A and B.

Would someone be kind enough to write out an example?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `...&& (OR(RecordType.DeveloperName = 'A', RecordType.DeveloperName = 'B')) ...`